# Cant load ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu onto a CD and tried to load it onto my laptop which has no operating system. The computer appears to startup and has the ubuntu logo on it then goes to a script page that says 'kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00006f00'
What does all this mean and what do I do now?
Thanks

Comment: The Ubuntu .iso file is too big to fit on a CD. To burn a DVD for installing Ubuntu, follow the instructions at the official Ubuntu website: [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or else get a flash drive that has at least 2GB  and follow the instructions at the official Ubuntu website: [How to create a bootable USB
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Comment: It will also be useful to add the brand and type of the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The CD is too small for the ISO for Ubuntu. Try a DVD instead and make sure the file is the right size which I belive its 981MB so almost a GB. Then burn the DVD and try the process again. It is very similar to burn the DVD as it is with a CD. Any blank DVD's will work and doesn't cost that much at Walmart or Office Depot. Hope this helps you out